# GMB API accounts.locations.reviews.list

Tags: python, java

Can  i get source code to get reviews using gmb python code also heard mybusiness is discontinued.
I tried using my business api is discontinued can i get the implementation process to look for extracting gmb reviews using python code.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [accounts.locations.review](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations.reviews/list), in JAVA, supposing that the variable mybusiness is taking care of authentication and API initialization:

```
MyBusiness.Accounts.Locations.Reviews.List reviewsList =
                            mybusiness.accounts().locations().reviews().list("your location name");
                    ListReviewsResponse response = reviewsList.execute();

List<Review> reviews = response.getReviews();
while(response.getNextPageToken()!=null) {
                        reviewsList.setPageToken(response.getNextPageToken());
                        response = reviewsList.execute();
                        reviews.addAll(response.getReviews());
                    }
for (Review review : reviews) {
  System.out.println(review.toString());
}
```

for python you can have a look at this link

> https://github.com/dresenhista/google_my_business